# Aggregate quarter to half year OLAP MDX

Tags: excel, mdx, olap

I have following time hierarchy:
`Year -> Quarter -> Week -> Day`. 
I managed to aggregate Q1/Q2 as Half Year 1 (H1) and Q3/Q4 as Half Year 2 (H2) for completed years in  the past (e.g. 2016):

```
Year    Quarter Ergebnis
Year 2016   Q1  2.688.627.598
Year 2016   Q2  2.114.089.713
Year 2016   Q3  3.064.536.554
Year 2016   Q4  3.451.472.537
**Year 2016 H1  4.802.717.311
Year 2016   H2  6.516.009.091**
```

I´m using following MDX Query to calculate member in OLAP:

```
Parent Hierarchy - [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date]
Parent Member -    [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[Year].&[2016]

MDX:
[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[Quarter].&[1]&[2016]
+
[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[Quarter].&[2]&[2016]
```

However this MDX Query doesn´t working for current year (2017):

```
Year     Quarter    Total
Year 2017   Q1  2.550.081.058
Year 2017   Q2  627.640.711
```

I can not even aggregate Q1, which is completed. Do you know workarounds how I can aggregate Q1 and Q2 for current year, even if Q2 is not completed yet?

Comment: There is no proper MDX code. Why don't you add extra levels: Half year and half quarter?

Comment: i´m power user and wanted to know if it´s makeable without editing the source. So there´s no way to get half year through mdx coding? But why does it work for previous years?

Comment: It's possible. Do you create calculated members to your hierarchy?

Comment: yes the members are appearing under quarter. E.g. for Last year: Year 2016 -> Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,H1,H2.

Answer (score 1):

You hard-coded the year value into MDX formula here:

```
[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[Quarter].&[1]&[2016]
+
[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[Quarter].&[2]&[2016]
```

Try instead:

```
[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].CurrentMember.Children.Item(0)
+
[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].CurrentMember.Children.Item(1)
```

Comment: Hi. And what about Parent Hierarchy - [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date]
Parent Member -    [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[Year].&[2016] ? Do i have to change them?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result you have:

```
Year        Quarter Total
Year 2016   Q1      2.688.627.598
Year 2016   Q2      2.114.089.713
Year 2016   Q3      3.064.536.554
Year 2016   Q4      3.451.472.537
```

So you want this?

```
Year        Half    Total
Year 2016   H1      4,802,717,311 
Year 2016   H2      6,516,009,091
```

You will need to add these two members on to a different dim/hier i.e. a `host` dimension that is not `[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date]`. I'll use `[Language].[Language]` - just change this to any other unused dim:

```
`[Language].[Language].[All].[H1]` 

 AGGREGATE(
  {
   [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].CurrentMember.Children.Item(0)
  ,[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].CurrentMember.Children.Item(1)
  }
   ,[Language].[Language].[All]
 )
```

and this:

```
`[Language].[Language].[All].[H2]` 

 AGGREGATE(
  {
   [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].CurrentMember.Children.Item(2)
  ,[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].CurrentMember.Children.Item(3)
  }
   ,[Language].[Language].[All]
 )
```

Then use these extra members, from the host dimension, in your pivot.

Comment: sorry i´m new to mdx and olap. What do i have to put for Parameter Hierarchy and Parameter Member?

Comment: This doesn´t work for me. Ideally i would have the members "H1" and "H2" under "Quarter" so that i can filter the two members without having Q1-Q4 displayed. So is there another way i can solve this problem? I also tried it with [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].CurrentMember.Children.Item(0)
+
[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].CurrentMember.Children.Item(1). But this doesn´t work. It only works when it´s hard-coded.

Comment: @ErhanAto I'll test this in AdvWrks tomorrow: using a host hierarchy is the way I've been approaching this the last few years.

Comment: How did you go ahead with testing?

Comment: any new approaches?